# FLVPlayback clip loading delays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, loading, flvplayback

I'm building a narrative click-through kiosk app in Flash/AS3. Currently, there are several (10+) locally loaded .flv files that I'm loading into an FLVPlayback component on the timeline.  I am experiencing loading delays and am wondering what the best practice / best case scenario for this case.  These are all using the "Load external video with playback component" option for Video importing.

So far I've tried implementing it two ways:

1. One frame, one FLVPlayback playback on the stage named "video_player", and upon the click through / user action to switch the video, I do the following:

   ```
   var new_flv:String = "next_flv.flv";

   video_player.stop();

   video_player.source("_flvs/"+new_flv);

   video_player.seek(0);

   video_player.play();
   ```

   This results in delays anywhere from a few seconds to 10 seconds.
2. This is unconventional to me, but I used multiple frames on the timeline.  Each frame had an FLVPlayback instance on the stage, each with a different relative path placed in the 'source' property in the component parameters (see http://www.ashleylovespizza.org/stuff/flv_example.png ).  The code is switching between frames based on frame label and then hitting play (autoplay is off in the component parameters as well).

   ```
   var new_flv_frame_name:String = "next_frame";

   this.gotoAndStop(new_flv_frame_name);

   this.video_player.play();
   ```

The issue, again, is that loading is taking a long time.  What could prevent this behavior?  One long flv that I seek() to different moments of time on the playhead?  Can I preload in a separate FLVPlayback instance, similar to double buffering?

Any tips or best practices are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not told me where the flv files are being loaded from (locally or remote), and as you have said you are building a kiosk style app, I am going to go out on a limb here and say that you should almost certainly use Adobe AIR for a kiosk app.

There is no reason for creating more than one `FLVPlayback` instance, its capable of playing multiple videos using `getVideoPlayer(index)`, its up to you to manage the streams by calling `close()` on them.

If you are loading files remotely, then using Adobe AIR you can download each video to a local folder using the `FileStream` class. This will speed up the process of playing back these files.

Comment: In the first line, I mention "several (10+) locally loaded .flv files".  So yes, locally.  That is my reason for confusion with such long load times.  Will having the fla publish to an .air app rather than a .swf cause load times to be better?  Also, I've added more code re: the switching of flvs.

Comment: This is useful though; I think I've been thinking of FLVPlayback as just a video player rather than a stream management component.  Will look more into the docs for this.

Comment: The reason I suggested AIR is because it is a desktop runtime, therefore no browser required, you will be able to make calls to the GC which cannot be done in the browser. I can't see why the loads times would be faster, but they certainly shouldn't take 10 secs in either environment. Using one component and managing the files without the use of frames should solve your issue here.